# click to navigate then show popup in the next page

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHa57.png)

flutter code :
i want to navigate to the next page then show popup at the time my screen loaded but i had that error -->
Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

Comment: Please provide more code related to your issue. Preferably, share a minimal code example to reproduce the error you have. One potential solution I can think of right now is adding `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async { // YOUR_CODE_TO_SHOW_POPUP }` inside `initState` of the screen you are opening